# How to 'strace' a unix domain socket?

Tags: linux-kernel, socket, strace

Kind of hard to explain but I noticed when `strace`ing the PID that has the socket open I cannot see any of the communication. How can I sit in the middle of a socket file to watch communication?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? In the mean time this might be helpful: http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace

Comment: When you say socket you mean a server running on a port on a host? Like a Apache web server running on hostA listening on port 80? Or do you truly mean a socket device file such as a pipe device?

Comment: The socket in this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types?

Comment: How exactly are you sending signals to a socket? Or do you not mean signals in the sense `kill -15 $pid`?

Comment: You can't send signals to a socket

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sockets are a kernel API for communication. Using the socket API, you can exchange data between two endpoints over TCP/IP connections, SCTP associations, UDP datagrams, or between two processes (datagram or connection) using Unix domain sockets...

Being a kernel API, any interaction with a socket is via system calls (`socket`, `bind`, `connect`, `listen`, `accept`, `sendmsg`, `send`, `recv`, `write/read`...).

So typically, `strace` will be able to trace those because `strace` traces system calls. The only communication mechanism that `strace` can't trace is IPC over shared memory (because reading/writing something in memory obviously doesn't involve a system call).

More likely, in your case, it's something else. My bet would be that the application is multi-threaded and you're not stracing the right thread. Or it could be that the application is setuid/setgid and not started as superuser.

If you want to strace what's being exchanged over Unix domain sockets, the options are:

- `strace` and other `ptrace` debugger (trace the server or the clients)
- The audit system (`auditd`/`auditctl`), again that traces the system calls
- use a `LD_PRELOAD` trick to wrap the system calls that interact with the socket
- instrument the code of the application to add logging there.
- systemtap and other low level kernel tracing/debugging systems as already mentioned
- insert a man in the middle.

For the MITM, you could for instance use `socat`. Here for a connection oriented Unix domain socket like for X11:

```
socat -x unix-listen:/tmp/.X11-unix/X42,fork unix:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
DISPLAY=:42 xlogo
```

Then, you see the X11 traffic that `xlogo` and the X server exchange.

Comment: @JMoore With `strace -ff -o log -s 20000 memcached...` you'll see all communication exchanged over the sockets. If there's communication not traced there, then that's not over sockets.

Comment: You can't MITM all communication on unix domain socket using socat. for example UDS allows you to send file descriptors using `sendmsg()` and `recievemsg()` but doint MITM then wouldn't make sense, as all action happens inside the kernel, like creating file descriptors for the recipient, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can't "strace a socket", strace works on processes, so you can strace all processes that talk to the socket, but you can't use strace to see absolutely all communication involving the socket. You *may* be able to get somewhere with dtrace or systemtap if they're available on your OS, but that's quite a bit of work.